# How to merge two dataframes with different columns in r (R-studio)?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have 2 large dataframes with different columns. The two dataframes could look like the small dataframes I have created below and named df1 and df2.

```
> df1
  casenumber income zipcode
1  1234-1234  20000    5270
2  2345-2345  30000    3320
3  3456-3456  40000    7000
> df2
  casenumber    name gender
1  3456-3456    Adam      1
2  1234-1234   Brian      1
3  2345-2345 Charlie      0
```

As shown above the column "casenumber" is the same in both dataframes. I have tried to merge/combine the dataframes so I get a dataframe as shown below.

```
> df3 
  casenumber income zipcode    name gender
1  1234-1234  20000    5270    Adam      1
2  2345-2345  30000    3320   Brian      1
3  3456-3456  40000    7000 Charlie      0
```

As we can see by looking at the column "casenumber" in the two original dataframes (df1 and df2) we can se that the data do not have the same row in df1 as it have in df2. Therefore I have to use the casenumber to make sure that the data from the dataframes will be merged/added correctly so the name belonging to casenumber 1234-1234 will be on the same row as the income belonging to casenumber 1234-1234.

Normally I have around 30 to 75 columns and 100,000 to 200,000 rows in total in the two dataframes.

I hope that you can help me with this problem. I have read multiple solutions to other's problems but they have had the same columns and/or the same rows.

I have read about different codes as "pd.concat" but as I understand it this function cannot be used in R-studio.

Functions as "rbind" cannot be used as the columns are different.

Comment: What you are describing is called a "left join". You can do: `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)` to get your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. But I have another question as I also tried to use the dplyr::left_join(df1, df2) in a situation where have added an extra row (observation) in df1 but I got the following error:
Error in `left_join()`:
! `by` must be supplied when `x` and `y` have no common variables.
ℹ Use `cross_join()` to perform a cross-join.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Sometimes one of my datasets is updated more often and will have new case numbers, which my second dataset (df2) would not have. 
In these cases the new case numbers (observations) would only have the  values from df1 and in the columns from df2 it would have "NA" or "NAN" because df2 dows not contain an observation for the specific casenumber.

I have tried to use other types of "join" codes from the dplyr-package but non of them have worked for me.

Is it possible to do this with a code or would I have to sort the new case numbers out and then add them after I have merged the datasets?

Comment: If you have some observations in df1 for which there are no observations in df2 then _of course_ the df2 columns will be NA (I.e. missing). What is it that you would like them to be?